# Why does an attached CRaSH shell throw a NullPointerException when issuing commands?

Tags: java, crash-shell

After [attaching a CRaSH shell](http://www.crashub.org/1.3/reference.html#_attach_mode) to a running java process using

> > crash.bat pid

starting CRaSH with a JDK, calling the help command returns an error

> % help
>
> help: exception: NullPointerException

This means that the commands are not compiled. Why does this happen despite
starting CRaSH shell with a JDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly noted, the CRaSH shell must run with a JDK as it needs the Java compiler.

The *same is required when attaching a CRaSH shell*. From the [CRaSH reference documentation](http://www.crashub.org/1.3/reference.html#_attach_mode): "CRaSH will hook into the targetted JVM instead of the JVM started by CRaSH"

**TL;DR**

***The process the CRaSH shell is attached to must run using a JDK!***

Comment: Add it to your question uning edit Funktion not as an answer

Comment: Why? Stackoverflow offers me to answer my own questions in a Q&A style, and this is what I did.

Comment: Ok. I not noticed that should be an answer. it Looks like an additial note to you question